# How can I create a rearrangeable list of items like OptionTree offers with the Theme Customization API?

Tags: theme-options, theme-customizer, api, plugin-option-tree

I have a theme that currently uses OptionTree, I'd like to move to the WP Theme Customizer API.

In OptionTree I can have a list of items that can be edited and drag and drop rearranged. Is there a way to accomplish this with the WordPress Customizer API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the Kirki toolkit: https://github.com/aristath/kirki
It has a "repeater" field that should do what you need.

It's still under heavy development and for the time being I've only added the ability to use a few field-types with it, so I guess it depends on what exactly the data you want to add & re-arrange is, but it's worth a look.

Comment: Thanks Aristeides, I've been looking at using Kirki for a while now. I've been reading up on it more and installed the latest plugin.